# NSwag: How do you Use Custom Value Object Types in C# -> Swagger -> C# client?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen, nodatime, nswag

I have an API that uses [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) types in both input and output. The types are serialized to strings in the JSON using the default Noda Time serialization format (which basically is the ISO-8601 format).

I have an object looking something like this:

```cs
public class NodaTimeDataStructure
{
    public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public DateInterval DateInterval { get; set; }
    public DateTimeZone DateTimeZone { get; set; }
    public Duration Duration { get; set; }
    public Instant Instant { get; set; }
    public Interval Interval { get; set; }
    public IsoDayOfWeek IsoDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public LocalDate LocalDate { get; set; }
    public LocalDateTime LocalDateTime { get; set; }
    public LocalTime LocalTime { get; set; }
    public Offset Offset { get; set; }
    public OffsetDate OffsetDate { get; set; }
    public OffsetDateTime OffsetDateTime { get; set; }
    public OffsetTime OffsetTime { get; set; }
    public Period Period { get; set; }
    public ZonedDateTime ZonedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

This will normally result in the following Swagger JSON:

```js
"NodaTimeDataStructure": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "dateTime", "duration", "instant", "interval", "isoDayOfWeek", "localDate", "localDateTime",
    "localTime", "offset", "offsetDate", "offsetDateTime", "offsetTime", "zonedDateTime"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "dateTime":       { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "instant":        { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "zonedDateTime":  { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "offsetDateTime": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "localDateTime":  { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "localDate":      { "type": "string", "format": "date" },
    "localTime":      { "type": "string", "format": "time" },
    "duration":       { "type": "string", "format": "time-span" },
    "dateInterval":   { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "string", "format": "date" } },
    "dateTimeZone":   { "$ref": "#/definitions/DateTimeZone" },
    "interval":       { "$ref": "#/definitions/Interval" },
    "isoDayOfWeek":   { "$ref": "#/definitions/IsoDayOfWeek" },
    "offset":         { "$ref": "#/definitions/Offset" },
    "offsetDate":     { "$ref": "#/definitions/OffsetDate" },
    "offsetTime":     { "$ref": "#/definitions/OffsetTime" },
    "period":         { "$ref": "#/definitions/Period" }
  }
}
```

This makes it impossible to convert back to the right Noda Time types in a C# client. Apart from the many different types having the exact same format (`"date-time"`) making a mapping impossible, certain types have unfortunate definitions. A `DateInterval` results in an array of `"date"`, since it's an enumerable of `LocalDate`, but a simple start/end date format would work much better. Other methods are created with a `$ref` to very elaborate objects containing fields of absolutely no interest. Be aware that all of these should be serialized as simple strings (arguably not the intervals).

I am able to create my own Type Mappers and adding them to a `AspNetCoreToSwaggerGeneratorSettings` like this:

```cs
var nodaTimeTypeMappers = new[]
{
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(DateInterval), "date-interval"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(DateTimeZone), "date-time-zone"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(Duration), "duration"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(Instant), "instant"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(Interval), "interval"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(IsoDayOfWeek), "iso-day-of-week"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(LocalDate), "local-date"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(LocalDateTime), "local-date-time"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(LocalTime), "local-time"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(Offset), "offset"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(OffsetDate), "offset-date"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(OffsetDateTime), "offset-date-time"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(OffsetTime), "offset-time"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(Period), "period"),
    CreateTypeMapper(typeof(ZonedDateTime), "zoned-date-time"),
};

foreach (var typeMapper in nodaTimeTypeMappers)
{
    settings.TypeMappers.Add(typeMapper);
}

PrimitiveTypeMapper CreateTypeMapper(Type type, string name)
{
    return new PrimitiveTypeMapper(type, s =>
    {
        s.Type = JsonObjectType.String;
        s.Format = "noda-time-" + name;
    });
}
```

to get something like this:

```js
"NodaTimeRequest": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "dateTime", "duration", "instant", "interval", "isoDayOfWeek", "localDate", "localDateTime",
    "localTime", "offset", "offsetDate", "offsetDateTime", "offsetTime", "zonedDateTime"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "dateTime":       { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "dateInterval":   { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-date-interval" },
    "dateTimeZone":   { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-date-time-zone" },
    "duration":       { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-duration" },
    "instant":        { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-instant" },
    "interval":       { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-interval" },
    "isoDayOfWeek":   { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-iso-day-of-week" },
    "localDate":      { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-local-date" },
    "localDateTime":  { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-local-date-time" },
    "localTime":      { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-local-time" },
    "offset":         { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-offset" },
    "offsetDate":     { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-offset-date" },
    "offsetDateTime": { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-offset-date-time" },
    "offsetTime":     { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-offset-time" },
    "period":         { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-period" },
    "zonedDateTime":  { "type": "string", "format": "noda-time-zoned-date-time" }
  }
}
```

This allows the formats to be used just like the existing formats (`"date-time"`, `"date"`, `"time"`, `"time-span"`), but I can't for the love of God figure out how to make the `swagger2csclient` use those formats to properly convert back to the corresponding Noda Time types. Am I generally missing something or is this currently not possible?

Comment: Haven't used Noda Time nor NSwag, but have used Swashbuckle.  Have a look at their documentation about  **Override Schema for Specific Types** [https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#override-schema-for-specific-types] Maybe it can help and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution for the Swagger json problem, but I can help with the C# client generation part.

Instead of generating the client from NSwag json, what we will do is have [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio) generate the client using reflection. I'm using "Web API via reflection" with Runtime set to "Default":

[image]

This generator "uses .NET reflection to analyze ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET Core controllers". Your mileage may vary of course - there is also a ".NET assembly" option and/or you might need to set the Runtime explicitly.

On the right hand pane, click "CSharp Client" and switch to the "CSharp Client" tab:

[image]

The first serving of secret sauce is visible in the above screenshot: we add `NodaTime` as an additional namespace.

Further down, we need to have NSwagStudio generate DTO classes and - here's the really important thing - **not** generate any of the NodaTime types by adding them to the "Excluded Type Names" list:

[image]

The type exclusion string I used is: `DateInterval,DateTimeZone,Duration,Instant,Interval,IsoDayOfWeek,LocalDate,LocalDateTime,LocalTime,Offset,OffsetDate,OffsetDateTime,OffsetTime,Period,ZonedDateTime,CalendarSystem,Era`.

There are numerous other options you will want to look at. Once you've done that, press `Generate Outputs` and your C# client will be generated.

---

Pasting the client in to a project which references NodaTime, we can see that the NodaTime types are used:

[image]

My test utilised your class `NodaTimeDataStructure` and this controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NodaTimeController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public NodaTimeDataStructure Get() => new NodaTimeDataStructure();
}
```

For the purposes of this test/demo, I built this into a library which targets .NET 4.8 and uses ASP.NET Core 2.2.